# working with fpdf, it not resulting the utf-8 character (persian)

Tags: pdf, fpdf

here after including the file of fpdf, and printing the text with English it's working fine

but when i use the Persian(مثال یک) it's showing some kind of different text.

```
$html = 'این یک مثال هست';

$pdf=new HTML2PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML2("<br><br><br><br><br>$html");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',3);
$pdf->Output();
```

Note: with english it results fine only problem with arabic or persian.

regards

Comment: Please clarify "different text". You write "hello", and then it shows "blue"? "Large"? "42"?

Comment: When i use persian text as value of $html it's not working

Answer (score 3):

**FPDF is a outdated (dead ?) project that natively does not handle UTF-8**, that explains why you get weird characters when you use arabic or persian.

The good new is you can use TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org) which handles perfectly UTF-8.

Thus, the migration from FPDF to TCPDF is quite easy since it uses the same methods (same methods names, same arguments) as FPDF.

AFAIK, arabic characters are perfectly supported by the Arial font.